# Qual a opção correta para se instanciar uma classe em PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, instanciar-objeto

Qual a opção correta para se instanciar uma classe em PHP?

Considerando que a classe é em discussão se chame `Atleta`:

1)

> ```
> $atleta=Atleta;
> ```

2)

> ```
> $atleta= new Atleta();
> ```

3)

> ```
> $atleta= Atleta();
> ```

Qual das 3 opções é a maneira correta para se instanciar uma classe em PHP?

Comment: É `$atleta= new Atleta();`

Comment: Ah eu prefiro `$atleta = new Atleta();`.

Comment: @Tmc essa edição deixou o titulo mais confuso, ele já estava bastante claro. Por isso, reverti sua edição para a anterior.

Comment: @Articuno, concordo fui rever e tornei mais confuso

Comment: @Stormwind só tiraria o destaque de quote, que pra esse caso nem seria preciso, mas não tinha reparado que eram 3 formas, a edição ficou boa.

Answer (score 8):

No contexto da pergunta seria a 2ª opção:

```
$atleta = new Atleta();
```

Mas vale lembrar que em PHP, não é necessário usar o parentesis `()` quando a classe não tem construtor ou o construtor não precisa de argumentos.

Então, isso também seria válido:

```
$atleta = new Atleta;
```

## Explicação de cada opção

Não sei se estou enganado, mas a pergunta parece muito com uma questão avaliativa. Então, supondo isso, não acho que seja legal apenas "dar a resposta certa", mas explicar o que cada coisa faz.

> `$atleta = Atleta;`

Geralmente, essa sintaxe é usada em PHP para obter o valor de uma constante.

Por exemplo:

```
const Atleta = 'Atleta';

// ou 

define('Atleta', 'Atleta');

$atleta = Atleta;
```

**Observação**: Ao tentar atribuir o valor de uma constante não definida, você receberá uma mensagem de erro do tipo `E_NOTICE` e o valor atribuído será uma string como nome da constante inexistente.

> `$atleta= Atleta();`

Já essa sintaxe acima é utilizada para a chamada direta de funções. Funções em PHP são chamadas com o uso o parentesis, podendo-se passar argumentos ou não.

Exemplo:

```
 function Atleta() {
       return 'Atleta';
}

$atleta = Atleta();
```

Comment: O último exemplo pode retornar um objeto: `function Atleta() { return new Atleta }`, não deixaria de ser uma instância de um objeto, então com exceção do 1º exemplo do AP, os demais estariam 'corretos'. É só um complemento pra resposta, sei que você está ciente :)

Comment: Eu não estava explicando o que pode retornar, mas sim a sintaxe que refere-se a cada item

Comment: Quem deu o negativo, poderia explicar o motivo? O que está de errado na resposta?

Answer (score 7):

É usar a opção 2, dessa forma:

```
$atleta= new Atleta();
```

> Pode consultar mais informações aqui [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php)

Answer (score 4):

Segundo o site oficial do [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.object.php), deve-se utilizar a instrução `new` para instanciar uma classe.

Caso você faça instância de um objeto genérico vazio o melhor caminho é utilizar o método abaixo:

```
$obj = new obj();
```

Sendo a maneira mais correta e rápida.

Só que indo mais além, no php7 existem outras maneiras de se instanciar um objeto vazio:

```
$obj1 = new \stdClass; //instancia o objeto stdClass
$obj2 = new class{}; //instancia uma classe anônima.
```

Em resumo, o mais utilizado pela comunidade: Bibliotecas, frameworks e etc é com os *colchetes*.